# Multiple Validation Rules Not Working

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I am trying to require certain fields when a checkbox is selected but whether the conditions are met are not, I am getting an error. I am no SF admin and am trying to figure this out on my own. Please help!

When inserting the following code, I get no syntax error. I am trying to say if the Academic Dishonesty checkbox is marked true, then require:
Instructor Name, Instructor Email, Course Name, Exam Name, Exam ID, Exam Taker Name, Time Stamp 1, Indicator 1, and Academic Dishonesty Summary to not be null.

**My Code**

```
IF(
OR(
(Academic_Dishonesty__c) = true ,
LEN (Instructor_Name__c)= null),True, False)&& IF(
OR(
(Academic_Dishonesty__c) = true ,
LEN (Instructor_Email__c) = null),True, False)&& IF(
OR(
(Academic_Dishonesty__c) = true ,
LEN (Course_Name__c)= null),True, False)&& IF(
OR(
(Academic_Dishonesty__c) = true ,
LEN (Exam_Name__c)= null),True, False)&& IF(
OR(
(Academic_Dishonesty__c) = true ,
LEN (Exam_ID__c)= null),True, False)&& IF(
OR(
(Academic_Dishonesty__c) = true ,
LEN (Exam_Taker_Name__c)= null),True, False)&& IF(
OR(
(Academic_Dishonesty__c) = true ,
LEN (Time_Stamp_1__c)= null),True, False)&& IF(
OR(
(Academic_Dishonesty__c) = true ,
LEN (Indicator_1__c)= null),True, False)&& IF(
OR(
(Academic_Dishonesty__c) = true ,
LEN (Academic_Dishonesty_Summary__c)= null),True, False)
```

When creating a case now, I am getting the

> This message will appear when Error Condition formula is true

Error Message at the top of the page whether the Academic Dishonesty box is unchecked or if the checkbox is checked and all the other fields listed have a value.

Answer (score 1):

As written, every condition in your formula would be true if `Academic_Dishonesty__c` is checked. It would read: `IF(OR(true, false) && OR(true, false) && ...)`, which will obviously tally to `true`. None of the other conditions are applied. You need to change the structure so that you `AND` join the condition of your checkbox with an `OR` join on any field being blank.

I have a couple strong recommendations:

- Always use `AND`/`OR` rather than `&&`/`||`, as it makes your syntax more consistent and much easier to read. It also makes it easier to wrap your head around what exactly you are enforcing with your logical structure.
- Never use `IF(condition, true, false)` as it can just be replaced by `condition`.
- If you see the exact same clause over and over again, there is probably a way to restructure your formula to use it just once.
- Check the syntax  of the formulas you use. `LEN` can never return null.

Corrected formula:

```
AND(
    Academic_Dishonesty__c,
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Instructor_Name__c),
        ISBLANK(Instructor_Email__c),
        etc.
    )
)
```